# Confusion on a lemma

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, absolute-value

So the lemma I had trouble understanding was this:

For all real numbers r, $−|r| ≤ r ≤ |r|$

The solution was something like this(used the definition of absolute values + division into cases)

> Suppose r is any real number. We divide into cases according to
> whether r ≥ 0 or r < 0.
>
> Case 1 (r ≥ 0):
>
> $|r| = r$. (By definition of absolute value)
>
> $−|r| < r$.(since $r$ is positive and $−|r|$ is negative)
>
> Thus it is true that $−|r| ≤ r ≤ |r|$.
>
> Qn: But based on what it said above, shouldn't it be more of $−|r| < r$ and $r=|r|$ not $−|r| ≤ r ≤ |r|$?

---

> Case 2 (r < 0):
>
> $|r|=−r$. (By definition of absolute value)
>
> Multiplying both sides by −1 gives that $−|r| = r$.
>
> $r < |r|($since $r$ is negative and $|r|$ is positive)
>
> Thus it is also true in this case that $−|r| ≤ r ≤ |r|$.
>
> Qn: But based on what it said above, shouldn't it be more of $r < |r| $ and $-r=|r|$ not $−|r| ≤ r ≤ |r|$ ?

---

> Hence, in either case, $−|r| ≤ r ≤ |r|$

Is the answer to my question in anyway linked to abusing inequalities?

Eg: Something like $1≤2$, although correct, it is imprecise. (sorry if this is totally off)

Comment: The inequality is not meant to be precise, but sometimes such imprecise inequality is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case $(1)$:

We have $$-|r|< r =|r|$$

but $-|r| < r$ would imply that $-|r|\le r$ and $r=|r|$ would imply that $r \le |r|$.

Hence we can write $-|r| \le r \le |r|$.

Note that $\le $ means less than or equal to.

Similarly for case $(2)$.

Explicit numerical example:

- If $r=2$, then we have $-2 < 2 = 2$, we also have the inequalities $-2 \le 2 \le 2$.
- If $r=-2$, then we have $-2 = -2 < 2$, which implies that $-2 \le -2 \le 2$.

Notice that for $-|r| \le r \le |r|$, equality is attained on at least one side. If both equalities are attained, then we have $r=0$.

Comment: The last part "if both equalities are attained, then we have r=0." confuses me. Can't you have equalities on both sides with r≠0? Eg: 2≤2≤2

Comment: If $ r \ne 0$, then $-|r|$ must be negative and $|r|$ must be positive. A number can't be positive and negative simultaneously.

Comment: In general, if you have $a \le b \le c$, yes, it's possible that we have $a=b=c$, I am referring to the special case of $-|r| \le r \le |r|$.